# Get NSArray values out of NSDictonary

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios4

I have a NSDictonary object that I am setting a set of objects as an array that has a corresponding key to as follows.

```
[dictionary setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Player3_Title", @"FirstName", @"LastName", @"Address3", @"SS3", nil] forKey: @"player3_infoKey"];
```

What I want to do is get those objects back into an array. When I try the following code this is what I get as an output.

```
stringsMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
    [stringsMutableArray addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"player3_infoKey"]];

NSLog(@"stringsMutableArray has values: %d", [stringsMutableArray count]);

NSLog(@"stringMutableArray: %@", [stringsMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]);


OUTPUT:
2012-01-01 08:50:29.869 test project[1165:f803] stringsMutableArray has values: 1
2012-01-01 08:50:29.870 test project[1165:f803] stringMutableArray: (
    "Player3_Title",
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Address3,
    SS3
)
```

Is there a way I can get the values for that key into an array? The reason I want to do this is that somewhere in the code I want to set text button values from that array.

```
FirstNameField1.text = [stringsMutableArray objectAtIndex:1];
LastNameField1.text = [stringsMutableArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you simply want to :

```
stringsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictionary objectForKey:@"player3_infoKey"]];
```

If you don't need it to be mutable:

```
stringsArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"player3_infoKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *myArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"player3_infoKey"];
[myArray objectAtIndex:0];  // Should return "Player3_Title"
```